# Android service does not create notifications or broadbast intents when launching the app first time

Tags: android, service, notifications, xmpp, broadcast

this is my service class. When i launch my app for the first time the service gets created but it does not show any notification until i close the app. when i close the app the service restarts and starts giving me notifications and sending broadcast.

```
public class XMPPService extends Service {
private XMPPTCPConnection mConnection = null;
private ChatManager chatManager;
int mNotificationId = 1;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                onHandleIntent(intent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) throws IOException, XMPPException, SmackException {
    if (mConnection == null) {
        mConnection = ProfileCreationActivity.returnConnection();
        if(!mConnection.isAuthenticated())
        mConnection.login(new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("username"), new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("password"));
        chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
        chatManager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListenerImpl());
        StanzaFilter filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);
        mConnection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
            }
        }, filter);

    }
    mConnection.addConnectionListener(new AbstractConnectionListener() {
        public void connectionClosed() {
            Log.i("connection", "closed");
        }

        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("connection", "closed on error");
        }

        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
            Log.i("reconnection", "failed");

        }

        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            if (mConnection.isAuthenticated()) {
                Log.i("isAuthenticated", String.valueOf(XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()));
            } else {
                try {
                    mConnection.login(new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("username"), new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("password"));
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("reconnection", "succesful");

        }


        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
            Log.i("reconnectingIn", String.valueOf(seconds));
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("service", "created");

}

private class ChatManagerListenerImpl implements ChatManagerListener {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
        if (!createdLocally) {
            chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                    Log.i("yeah :", "yeah");
                    new DBHelper(getApplicationContext()).addMessage(message.getBody().toString(), message.getFrom().toString().substring(0, 12), false);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.user);
                    builder.setContentText(message.getBody().toString());
                    builder.setContentTitle(message.getFrom().toString().substring(0, 12));
                    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction("com.SINGLE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED");
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    Log.i("Notification : ", "notified");
                }
            });
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mConnection.disconnect();
    Log.i("service :", "destroyed");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

i am starting my service in my main activity while checking my connection to the xmpp server. heres the code :

```
private class CheckConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, XMPPTCPConnection> {

    @Override
    protected XMPPTCPConnection doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (!XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()) {
            try {
                XMPPClient.getConnection().login(new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("username"), new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("password"));
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return XMPPClient.getConnection();

        } else

        {
            return XMPPClient.getConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(XMPPTCPConnection con) {
        if (isMyServiceRunning(XMPPService.class) && XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()) {
            Log.i("Service is :", "Running");
            getForms(con);

        } else {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XMPPService.class);
            startService(serviceIntent);
            if (XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()) {
                getForms(con);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: show your AndroidManifest

Comment: i am using service not intent service so it is not an override that is wh i have to call it myself